# Is manual JWT token authentication OK?

Tags: python, flask, jwt

I build a graphql web server using flask. Now I'm trying to use jwt for user authentication. So I created 2 more endpoint for login and registration. After user login he gets a access token. But I only need to protect one schema (the user schema) so I can't protect the whole graphql endpoint. What I did was to get the token from the request header and and decode it to get the user information. It's working perfectly but I'm worried that it might be a security leak. Is it possible for someone to easily access the access token from the schema? This is my schema code

```
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    node = relay.Node.Field()
    user = graphene.Field(User)
    def resolve_user(self, info):
         query = User.get_query(info)
         token = info.context.headers.get("AUTHORIZATION")
         token_type = decode_token(token)["type"]
         email = None
         if token_type == "access":
               email = decode_token(token)["identity"]
         return query.filter_by(email=email).first()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the token signed? At least the token should be signed and instead of just decoding it, you should verify the token. Otherwise it's quite pointless.

Comment: What do you mean by signed? I'm using the token generated from flask-jwt-extended

Comment: Normally your token consist of 3 parts, header, payload and signature. Header and payload are just base64 encoded JSON and readable for everyone. The signature is a hash over header and payload. With that, you can guarantee that the token was not manipulated. You use a secret or key to create and verify the signature. Check https://jwt.io to get a better idea. You can examine your token in the debugger of that site to see what's in it.

Comment: The idea of signing is, your graphql server should be capable of figuring out if the JWT obtained is signed by an auth server it trusts -in this case your backend for your login endpoint.

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean . I should verify that the token is valid right? Using my secret key

Comment: @Marvin that's right!

Comment: If you're using flask-jwt-extended, you can use the `jwt_optional` decorator to make sure everything is properly validated and be able to differentiate between a logged in user and a non-logged in user. http://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optional_endpoints.html